# Mascheroni Construction of the Heptadecagon

Tags: geometry

Since Gauss proved that the heptadecagon is constructible with ruler and compass, there were found plenty of ways of constructing it, some of them are pretty clever (e.g. [DeTemple](https://www.jstor.org/stable/2323939) and [Ma Long](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=http://www.cgn.net.cn/cms/document/attach_manager!download.action%3Fid%3D4028806d5bc82981015bcd4241ac03fd&ved=2ahUKEwjolrHU-_jiAhUDLLkGHRolA54QFjANegQIARAB&usg=AOvVaw2qotTVEUcddTuH0HFdWIVi)).

On the other hand, there is a theorem due to Mascheroni which states that any polygon that is constructible with ruler and compass can be constructed with compass only (the ones called Mascheroni constructions). I found some interesting Mascheroni constructions for the pentagon, including a pretty amazing result showing the construction of the pentagon with only 7 circles (see it [here](https://www.cut-the-knot.org/pythagoras/MascheroniPentagon.shtml)).

However, in my research I didn't find any clever Mascheroni construction of the heptadecagon (besides the ones that are just translations of Mascheroni methods to some operations between segment and circles, such as finding the midpoint). So I was wondering:

> Which is the Mascheroni construction of the heptadecagon with the least number of circles that is known? Is there any work in this direction?